# Web push notification click action tracking

Tags: web, notifications, click, push, action

I am developing a website to send push notifications to my subscribers' using Firebase Cloud Messaging (Chrome & Firefox browsers) without using any third-party API. Push notification sending is working fine, but I don't know that "How to track notification click action". I can track click action by using JavaScript (ajax call) but I am not sure this will be right choice to proceed. 
For example, consider that I am sending push notification to 1,00,000 subscribers in that if 50,000 subscribers clicked on that notification in few seconds, then it will be burden to the server. Is it possible?
Or Is there any other way to track push notifications click report from FCM. If so how to accomplish this?
Please help me out!

Comment: did you get any luck with it? I am curious to know about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the date to your URL like this:

```
yoursite.com/article/lorem-ipsum?utm_source=notification&utm_campaign=1554750619
```

Then on your GA you can generate reports based on your campaigns.